# How to properly override equality?

Tags: c#, binary, overloading, operator-keyword

I am still new to overloading operators. I thought i was doing a great job until i hit this problem. NullReferenceException is thrown on the != operator. I assume its using it in the CompareTo method but i'm not totally sure. If anyone can point me in the right direction i would be very grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            tasks.Add(new Task( "first",  DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)));
            tasks.Add(new Task( "second", DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)));
            tasks.TrimExcess();
            tasks.Sort();
        }
    }
    public class Task : IComparable
    {
        public Task()
        {
        }
        public Task(string nameIn, DateTime dueIn)
        {
            nameOfTask = nameIn;
            dateDue = dueIn;
        }
        DateTime dateDue;
        string nameOfTask;

        public static bool operator <(Task t1, Task t2)
        {
            return (t1.dateDue < t2.dateDue);
        }
        public static bool operator >(Task t1, Task t2)
        {
            return (t1.dateDue > t2.dateDue);
        }
        public static bool operator ==(Task t1, Task t2)
        {
            return (t1.dateDue == t2.dateDue);
        }
        public static bool operator !=(Task t1, Task t2)
        {
                return (t1.dateDue != t2.dateDue);

        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Int32.Parse(this.dateDue.ToString("yyyymmddhhmmss"));
        }
        public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;    

            Task t = obj as Task;
            if ((System.Object)t == null) return false;
            return (this.dateDue == t.dateDue);
        }
        int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return 1;

            Task t = obj as Task;
            if (t != null)
            {
                return this.dateDue.CompareTo(t.dateDue);
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Task");
        }
    }
}
```

When i comment out the binaory operators the program functions as intended. My question is how can i protect my binary operators from null references so i can keep them for manual comparisons? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: One of the `Task` objects that you are comparing with `!=` is set to `null`.

Comment: Right-o..  You need to assume `t1` and/or `t2` can be null in all those static functions..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both the answers given so far are wrong. The accepted answer is wrong because it accidentally recurses. The other answer is wrong because it says that null is not equal to null.

Your implementations of the operators are all wrong; **they are required to correctly handle null inputs.**

Your implementation of GetHashCode is deeply broken; you attempt to put a fourteen digit number into a format that can accept nine digits. Simply call GetHashCode on the date; there is no need to go through this rigamarole of turning it into a string and then turning that into a number!

The right way to write the code is to use `object.ReferenceEquals` to do reference comparisons rather than using the `==` and `!=` operators; it is far too easy to do an accidental recursion.

The typical pattern goes like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(Task t1, Task t2)         
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(t1, t2)) return true;
    // All right. We know that they are (1) not the same object, and
    // (2) not both null. Maybe one of them is null.
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(t1, null)) return false;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(t2, null)) return false;
    // They are not the same object and both are not null.
    return t1.dateDue == t2.dateDue;
}

public static bool operator !=(Task t1, Task t2)         
{
    // Simply call the == operator and invert it.
    return !(t1 == t2);
}

public override bool Equals(object t)
{
    return (t as Task) == this;   
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.dateDue.GetHashCode();
}
```

The other comparison operators are left as an exercise.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the fix! I guess I should try even the simplest snippets in the debugger before posting...

Comment: I get it! Thank you maestro, this fixes so much. my problem was i was using my logic to test the compare to instead of trying to use the object.ReferenceEquals. Thank you for your patience and your answers.

Comment: For good measure one could also implement `IEquatable<Task>`. That's more important for valuetypes to avoid boxing, but it doesn't hurt doing with reference types too.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of the `Task` objects that you are comparing with `!=` is set to `null`. The built-in operator `!=` compares the references and does not break, but your operator tries to dereference the task, and breaks.

```
public static bool operator !=(Task t1, Task t2) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(t1, null)) {
        return !ReferenceEquals(t2, null); // return true only if t2 is *not* null
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(t2, null)) {
        return true; // we know that t1 is not null
    }
    return (t1.dateDue != t2.dateDue);
}
```

This implementation returns `false` when both tasks are `null`. You should implement a symmetric null checking in the `==` operator.

Comment: Thank you, i tried something like this only to get a stack overflow, i see where i went wrong. Could you explain what Symmetric null checking is (the google seems confused about it)?

Comment: @Powe8525 When I mentioned that the behavior of your `bool operator ==` needs to be symmetric with that of your `bool operator !=`, I meant that it should treat two `null` values as equal, and that `null` should not be equal to a non-null value. The implementation of `!=` from the answer adheres to these rules, so the implementation of `==` should follow them as well.

Comment: @Powe8525: You are correct; the code given here is broken because it calls itself. The correct code is to begin with `if (object.ReferenceEquals(t1, null)) { return !object.ReferenceEquals(t2, null); }`

Comment: @EricLippert Since you're on this thread, may I ask you a quick off-topic question about the rationale of allowing both `==` and `!=` to be overridden separately? I think Ada's rule of overriding "not equals" `/=` implicitly when "equals" `=` is overridden, and prohibiting overrides of `/=` makes sense.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I have always found that to be a bit of an odd rule. You can override == and != independently so that objects with NaN-like semantics -- that are equal to nothing and unequal to nothing -- can be implemented. Similarly the language does not attempt to enforce normal arithmetic invariants; for example, `x >= y` is not required to be the same as `x > y || x == y`.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks! I knew there must be the reason behind it, and now I know what it is.

Comment: SQL behaves in this way.  `null` is equal to nothing, not even another `null`.  `null == null` is false.

Comment: I know no BCL type for which `a != b` is not equivalent to `!(a == b)`. In particular `double.NaN != double.NaN` returns true.

Answer (score -4):

```
 public static bool operator !=(Task t1, Task t2) 
        { 
              if (null == t1 || null == t2) { return false;}
                return (t1.dateDue != t2.dateDue); 

        }
```

Comment: Hmm, and if `t1` is null and `t2` is not null, wouldn't you expect this to return `true`?

Comment: It was an example.  The op should be smart enough to define their own logic.

Comment: You also forgot casting `t1`/`t2` to `object` before comparing with `null`. And messing up the important special case of `null == null` isn't excused by simply saying this is an example.

Comment: The original poster is asking the question because **they do not know how to do it correctly**. Assuming that the original poster is "smart enough" to detect and fix your bugs is *denying the premise of the question*.

Comment: It is not a bug.  It is an example.  Whether two nulls are equal is an implementation detail that can not simply be assumed.  It is up to the OP to define the return results.  The OP is comparing the equality of properties.  They do not give us enough information for any of us to assume what the proper return value is when one or more of the inputs are null.